# Gravar dados MYSQL no formato pt-br / UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, conexão, phpmyadmin

Galera como faço pra salvar dados no banco de dados no formato brasileiro com acentos, eu usava isso na conexão

`mysqli_set_charset($conexão, 'utf8');`

mas agora meu codigo esta todo em PDO como faço pra salvar esse dados em utf8 no banco PHPMYadmin?

```
<?php

//Pagina de Conexão com o banco de dados

//Define as Variaveis PDO para conexão
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' ); //Local de acesso do banco
define( 'DB_NAME', 'ifsp' ); //Nome do banco de dados
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' ); //Usuario do banco
define( 'DB_PASS', '' ); //Senha do banco de dados

// Tentar conexao
try 
{
    $pdo = new PDO( 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS );

    //Se erro ativa o catch 
} catch ( PDOException $e ) 
{
    //Exibe o erro 
    echo "Erro: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para definir o conjunto de caracteres no *PDO* deves especificar no *DSN* com os restantes parâmetros da conexão.

```
...
try 
{
    $pdo = new PDO( 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . '; charset=utf8;', DB_USER, DB_PASS );

    //Se erro ativa o catch 
} catch ( PDOException $e ) 
{
...
```

Ou ainda especificando nas opções do *PDO*.

```
...
$opc= array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME;
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opc);
...
```

---

[PDO MySQL DSN - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)

Answer (score 3):

Existem duas maneiras:

- pelo DNS;
- pelo comando `SET NAMES` (que pode ser executado na inicialização)

O ideal é utilizar as duas, porque antes do PHP 5.3.6 o parâmetro `charset` do DNS era ignorado.

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host={$host};dbname={$database};charset=utf8"; // PHP >= 5.3.6
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8', // PHP < 5.3.6
); 
$conexao = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
```

Eu prefiro utilizar uma condição para executar o comando apenas quando necessário:

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host={$host};dbname={$database};charset=utf8";
$conexao = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.6', '<')) {
    $conexao->exec('SET names utf8;');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
$pdo = new PDO( 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS.':charset=utf8' );
```

ou

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass, 
               array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                     PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

De todos vocês deu muito certo Obrigado

```
    <?php

//Pagina de Conexão com o banco de dados

//Define as Variaveis PDO para conexão
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' ); //Local de acesso do banco
define( 'DB_NAME', 'ifsp' ); //Nome do banco de dados
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' ); //Usuario do banco
define( 'DB_PASS', '' ); //Senha do banco de dados

// Tentar conexao
try 
{
    $options= array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    ); 
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME;
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);

    //Se erro ativa o catch 
} catch ( PDOException $e ) 
{
    //Exibe o erro 
    echo "Erro: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
}
```